# MSVC lambda with two auto params of same type

Tags: visual-studio, templates, lambda, c++14, generic-lambda

It seems that Visual Studio behaves differently from GCC and Clang given the following code:

```
auto f2 = [](auto x, decltype(x) y)
{
  return x + y;
};
f2(1, 2);
```

Clang and GCC will accept this, but MSVC will complain with the message

> *error C3536: 'x': cannot be used before it is initialized*

Is there a workaround in order to force the 2 parameters types to be equal?

Nb : this problem can be reproduced with Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and Pre-2018

See [this code on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+test_lambda()+%0A%7B%0A++auto+f1+%3D+%5B%5D(auto+x,+auto+y)%0A++%7B%0A++++return+x+%2B+y%3B%0A++%7D%3B%0A++f1(1,+2)%3B%0A%0A++auto+f2+%3D+%5B%5D(auto+x,+decltype(x)+y)%0A++%7B%0A++++return+x+%2B+y%3B%0A++%7D%3B%0A++f2(1,+2)%3B%0A%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+MSVC+19+2017+RTW+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+MSVC+19+2017+RTW',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) (where you can switch between different compilers)

---

Edit:

The behavior of this code is not what one might expect when reading it: it will compile whenever decltype(y) is convertible to decltype(x), and not only when they are equal.

So, both @n.m. and @max66 answers are correct: the first is if you want to force the types to be equal, and the second is if you want to work with is_convertible.

I have accepted the second, since it preserves the original code behavior (although, the original code was probably erroneous : a comparison on type equality was better in my case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked but... maybe you can impose it inside the lambda, using another lambda

```
auto f2 = [] (auto x, auto y)
 { return [](decltype(x) a, decltype(x) b) {return a + b;}(x, y); };
```

Comment: Nice idea ! However in this case `f2('c', 2)`will compile (comparing char and int).

Comment: @PascalT. - yes; but `f2('c', 2)` will compile also with `[](auto x, decltype(x) y)` (Barry corrected me about this point). If you want that `f2('c', 2)` doesn't compile, is another type of problem.

Comment: You're right. The original code was compiling correctly with f('c', 2). I do not know if it was intended, although : I am porting some code to windows, and I need to check the original intent of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto f2 = [](auto x, auto y)
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(y)>::value, 
                "Argument types must be the same");
  return x + y;
};
```

For more faithful emulation of the original behaviour, you can try `is_convertible` instead of `is_same` (but some MSVC versions ICE on it for some reason).

Comment: Nice ! I like it, since we have the added benefit of having a more human-friendly compiler output in case of a type error

Comment: Both your answer and @max66  are correct,  according to me !